# Bound of $\log \det$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, complex-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

I want to find a bound to the function

$$R(d_i, d_j)=\log\det\left\{\mathbf{I}+\frac{d_{i}^{-\alpha}\mathbf{H}_{i}\mathbf{v}_{i}\mathbf{v}_{i}^{H}\mathbf{H}_{i}^{H}}{d_{j}^{-\alpha}\mathbf{H}_{j}\mathbf{v}_{j}\mathbf{v}_{j}^{H}\mathbf{H}_{j}^{H}+\sigma^{2}\mathbf{I}}\right\}$$ in terms of only $d_j$. 
So I came up with the following. I want to claim the the RHS is a upper bound to the LHS for some $d_i>\gamma$. Could someone please tell me if my claim is correct? 
$$\log\det\left\{\mathbf{I}+\frac{d_{i}^{-\alpha}\mathbf{H}_{i}\mathbf{v}_{i}\mathbf{v}_{i}^{*}\mathbf{H}_{i}^{*}}{d_{j}^{-\alpha}\mathbf{H}_{j}\mathbf{v}_{j}\mathbf{v}_{j}^{*}\mathbf{H}_{j}^{*}+\sigma^{2}\mathbf{I}}\right\}\leq \log\det\left\{\mathbf{I}+\frac{1}{d_{j}^{-\alpha}\mathbf{H}_{j}\mathbf{v}_{j}\mathbf{v}_{j}^{*}\mathbf{H}_{j}^{*}+\sigma^{2}\mathbf{I}}\right\}$$

where $\mathbf{H_i}$, $\mathbf{H_j}$ are complex valued constant matrices. Then $\mathbf{v_i}$, $\mathbf{v_j}$ are complex valued constant column vectors. $\alpha$ is a real positive constant and $d_i$, $d_j$ are non negative real valued scalar variables, $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity matrix. The superscript $^*$ is the conjugate transpose (Hermitian).

Both $\mathbf{v_i}$,$\mathbf{v_j}$ exclude the all zero vector. Similarly both  $\mathbf{H_i}$, $\mathbf{H_j}$ exclude all zero matrix. And $\sigma^2>0$ a real constant. The matrix inverse is defined in the usual way.
I did this for scalar case and it hold easily since we can always find a $d_i$ such that

$$\log\left\{1+\frac{\frac{a}{d_{i}}}{\frac{b}{d_{j}}+\sigma^{2}}\right\}\leq \log\det\left\{\mathbf{I}+\frac{1}{\frac{b}{d_{j}}+\sigma^{2}}\right\}$$ for $a,$ $b$ positive.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The inequality is certainly false without some normalization requirements for the $\mathbf{v}_j$ and $\mathbf H_j$. Indeed, you can take $\mathbf v_i=0$, and then your LHS is zero, while your RHS is positive (if $\sigma^2>0$, for instance).

Comment: Thank you very much. In fact I can make $v_i$, $v_j$ both non zero. And $\sigma^2>0$ as you mention. Will the inequality hold then?

Comment: No. You can still make $H_j$ and $v_j$ have very small norm. The only chance your inequality has (and then I'm not sure if it holds) is if you have a restriction like asking for the norm of $v_j$ and $H_j$ to be $1$. It might help you if you first consider the inequality for $1\times1$ matrices (i.e. numbers).

Comment: Thank you. But is not that if  $H_j v_j$ has small norms that affects both RHS and LHS ?

Comment: Thank you. I have been working with the wrong inequality. I corrected it above. sorry.

Comment: There is also the problem of what you mean by the fraction. The matrices in the numerator and denominator do not necessarily commute, so you need to specify what the fraction means.

Comment: I take the fraction as $A/B = AB^{-1}$. Thank you.

Comment: That complicates things, because with that defintion $A/B$ may fail to be positive definite (which the expressions $v_iv_i^*$, etc., seem to imply is important) even if $A$, $B$ are. A most reasonable definition is $B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}$. But, of course, it is a matter of choice.